# IntelliJ IDEA does not save system settings on exit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, system-setting

my IntelliJ IDEA does not save my settings on exit. I have looked in the settings and have found nothing. My problem is: when I exit intelliJ and I reopen it my project might be opened but I have to click view and find the class manually and reopen it (it used to be once I reopen it, it reopened everything I had). Also it does not remember my maven directory so I have to set it up manually on every start. If I am missing something or some plugin please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Is the project imported or is it locally created on the pc you are having this problem? If you're trying to import, make sure you select maven as project type and select the pom.xml when trying to import it. If you're creating a project from scratch, just make sure the proper project type was selected.

Comment: Closed the project, reopened it through the POM and through a new import and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Are you on OSX by any chance?

Comment: Nah, winwods 7 64bit